# CapsLock password message in TEdit visually fails with VCL Styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, vcl-styles

The CapsLock message when using password in TEdit get buggy when using VCL Style. This is how looks like without style:

[image]

and this with VCL Style on:

[image]

The message is in portuguese, but I don't think this matter. Using Windows 10 style in Delphi Seattle 23.0.21418.4207 (with Update 1).

Comment: Delphi VCL styles are buggy. I can suggest you to use RRUZ's https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils

Comment: Found it. VCL Style Utils, like a lot of other things, solves the bug. Just had to add the `Vcl.Styles.Utils.ScreenTips` in the uses.

Comment: Astounding that VCL styles are still so buggy. So much for the new focus on quality.

Comment: This issue was fixed on RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin.

Answer (score 5):

Found it. VCL Style Utils, like a lot of other things, solves the bug. Just had to add the `Vcl.Styles.Utils.ScreenTips` in the uses.